# MySQL Join to include non-matching records in WHERE Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need to output data from two table if it exists.

I want to select all records in Table 1 for display in a PHP Recordset using a dynamic html table.  I also need to display some data from Table 2 if it exists.  My existing query is not selecting all the data I need from the two tables.

**Table 1**

```
EmpNum     FirstName   EmpType
541        Robert      88
222        Samuel      88
521        Anthony     88
```

**Table 2**

```
ID   SecretKey     NickName
541  6565          Bob
222  9999          Sam
```

I also want to "join" this data with another table that ***may or may not*** have matches.  This is throwing off my results.

```
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, Table2.ID, Table2.SecretKey, Table2.NickName FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
```

This query is omitting the EmpNum 521 from the tabular data because my WHERE clause does not find a match.

I'd like to have all the records display from Table 1 and then append data from Table 2 if a match exists.

Example **DESIRED** output:

```
EmpNum     FirstName   EmpType     SecretKey     NickName
541        Robert      88          6565          Bob
222        Samuel      88          9999          Sam
521        Anthony     88
```

In this example above Anthony is still displayed even though he has not records in Table 2.

How do I alter my join to achieve this.

Comment: Switch to explicit `join` syntax and use a `left outer join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join -

```
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, Table2.ID, Table2.SecretKey, Table2.NickName 
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.EmpNum = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.EmpType = '88'
```

You can continue to outer join additional tables as you need, getting all of the data from the first table and then only matching data from the subsequent tables.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, Table2.ID, Table2.SecretKey, Table2.NickName 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
UNION ALL
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, null, null, null
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select 1 from Table2
    where Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
)
```

which becomes a bit clearer by replacing the comma join with an explicit one

```
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, Table2.ID, Table2.SecretKey, Table2.NickName 
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
UNION
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, null, null, null
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select 1 from Table2
    where Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
)
```

However, this is the same as:

```
SELECT Table1.EmpNum, Table1.FirstName, Table2.ID, Table2.SecretKey, Table2.NickName 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.EmpNum=Table2.ID AND Table1.EmpType = '88'
```